555 Bi-Stable mode gets triggered by reset pin
I prepared a Bi-stable 555 circuit based on below schematic. Threshold pin is connected to ground as suggested. Many tutorials left it to float. I remember like once I faced some issue by leaving threshold pin unconnected. So I preferred this schematic.
https://www.circuitbasics.com/555-timer-basics-bistable-mode/
The circuit is working fine with buttons. But when I replace reset button with wires and make momentary contact, 555 timer gets triggered. If I make long contact then it's not triggering. The video demo can be seen in this YouTube video. It is strange to see a reset pin is triggering 555 timer.
https://youtube.com/shorts/eZjrpworO7U?si=r4tzwPJ8h_hdobnE
The breadboard connection can be seen in this image. Top most line is VCC (5v) and second line is ground. If I add a 10u capacitor between pin 4 and ground, the issue perishes. Can someone help me to understand the issue?


There is no proper schematic for your circuit, but  I can see it lacks a power supply bypass capacitor.
Preferably something like 100uF electrolytic in parallel with 100nF ceramic.
The bipolar 555, as you appear to have, draws nasty current spikes when switching.

The schematic is exactly the same in the tutorial link. https://www.circuitbasics.com/555-timer-basics-bistable-mode/I have something like 100 uF capacitor in the power adapter. So, I didn't add any capacitor in my breadboard.
